# Error after installing packages with snap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snapcraft

I've used the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) package manager to install packages and I'm always
getting the same error, even with the simple hello world example:

```
$ sudo snap install hello
$ hello
cannot create user data directory: /home/aaa/snap/hello/20: Bad file descriptor
```

Running with `sudo` solves the problem for the `hello` program, but why do I even need to do `sudo`?

BTW, for the other packages (Meshlab, CloudCompare) it doesn't work also with `sudo` and gives different errors. For example:

```
~$ sudo cloudcompare.ccViewer 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

The snap version and Ubuntu distro are:

```
$ snap version
snap    2.22.7
snapd   2.22.7
series  16
ubuntu  14.04
kernel  4.4.0-64-generic
```

Comment: Probably bad permissions to `/home/aaa/snap/` or rest of them... if you run it firstly with root, then root created those files... and normal user cant write there.

Comment: @FlashThunder But I cannot install without `sudo`, similar to `sudo apt-get ...`. I also checked and I have full premissions for `/home/aaa/snap/`.

Comment: @Flash if this were permission-related I would expect to see that reflected in the error (e.g. permission denied).

Comment: Can you add some detail about what distro you're running this on? Also, the output of "snap version" would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance your home directory is an nfs share with no-write-by-root enabled? If so, try logging in as another user that has a local home.

Also, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1625279

Comment: Please [edit] to add a summary of that bug's relevance to this question so others don't have to visit it to figure anything out.